# git - losing files when cloning from a case-sensitive filesystem to a case-insensitive filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, git, clone

I am on a mac and trying to clone linux man pages using this command:

```
git clone http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages
```

and got this warning message after the clone is done:

```
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'man2/_Exit.2'
  'man2/_exit.2'
  'man3/NAN.3'
  'man3/nan.3'
```

I checked my `man2` directory and only `_exit.2` exists, `_Exit.2` wasn't cloned on my mac.

how can I solve this problem and get a full clone from the remote linux server?

thanks in advance!

Comment: On my system (OpenSUSE), _Exit just sources _exit, and NAN is a symlink to HUGE_VAL.

Comment: Use case-sensitive FS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS uses a case-insensitive file system, whereas most Linux distributions use case-sensitive. You won't be able to copy multiple files with names differing only by case onto your Mac and preserve both versions, as far as I know.

I believe you would need to rename the source files on their source server, which clearly isn't an option for you here. If you have access to a Linux machine, or a Linux server, you could clone the repository there, and then rename them, using `rename` (which you may need to install, depending on the Linux distro) and a Regular Expression.

That may be more trouble than it's worth, depending on the contents of those particular files.

Answer (score 1):

Use Disk Utility in macOS to create a new disk image that is case sensitive, e.g. `APFS (Case-sensitive)`.

Then use terminal to change directory into that disk, then run:

```
git clone xxxxx
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).